# In R, how to select particular rows of records

Tags: r

I have a list of cancer patient records, multiple dates per patient, multiple records per day, primary and secondary diagnoses. Some diagnoses are considered primary & others secondary based on established criteria.

I am trying to modify the data to result in one row per patient with the primary diagnosis. Here I think primary diagnosis can be identified by either (mildly preferred) a list of words in the diagnosis field (metastasis, secondary, etc) or a list of codes in icd9 field.

Let's say this is my data:

```
id       date        icd9         type 
1     2018-01-01     174.8      breast cancer
1     2018-01-01     198.5      bone metastasis     
1     2018-06-01     197.0      pulmonary secondary
2     2018-05-05     198.5      bone metastasis
2     2018-05-05     162.0      lung cancer
3     2018-06-10     196.9      secondary to distant
3     2018-06-10     174.8      breast cancer
```

I would like the final dataset to look like this:

```
id       date        icd9        type 
1     2018-01-01     174.8      breast cancer
2     2018-05-05     162.0      lung cancer
3     2018-06-10     174.8      breast cancer
```

I have tried to order the dataset and pull the first record for each patient as follows:

```
mydata <- mydata[order(mydata$id, mydata$data),]
p   <- by(cancer, cancer$id, head, n=1)    
p   <- do.call("rbind", as.list(p))
```

However that erroneously results in the **first** record being retrieved, rather than the **primary**:

```
id       date        icd9         type 
1     2018-01-01     174.8      breast cancer
2     2018-05-05     198.5      bone metastasis
3     2018-06-10     196.9      secondary to distant
```

At the moment I am deleting all the records with secondary diagnoses `p <- mydata[!grepl("[S|s]econdary|[M|m]etast", mydata$type),]` , before selecting the first record as above. However it seems inelegant.

Any great ideas would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you choosing only those with cancer? What is the criteria for choosing a row?

Comment: Please clarify what is the condition for primary diagnosis?

Comment: @user14624243 Instead of using `grep` to search for keywords, I would instead create a vector of all primary malignancy diagnosis `icd9` codes, and then for each `id` include rows where the `icd9` code is found in the vector (unclear if you can have or want to include patients with multiple primary malignancies). The [SEER program](https://seer.cancer.gov/tools/casefinding/) has some resources that may be helpful for developing/downloading a list of relevant codes to use as your vector of codes, though more recently has focused on ICD10.

Comment: @Ben - Thanks, that's a good route to chase down! For this purpose, I can include patients with multiple primary malignancies.